What is the wire between these switches and how are they able to work independently?
Pictured is a junction box in a bathroom (in the USA). The switch on the right operates a light, and the left switch operates an overhead exhaust fan. I am inexperienced but have never seen one switch wired to another like this, and yet both switches can operate independently.
Can someone help me understand what is the connection between point 2 and 4 doing?

I'm asking because I'm hoping to replace the right (light) switch with this dimmer switch (pictured).


I'll basically say the same thing as KMJ, but from a different perspective - hopefully easier for an inexperienced person to understand.
What seems to be happening here is that power comes in through wire (3). At the point where it enters the right switch, it's also permanently coupled to the (2-4) wire. So basically the path of the power splits into two paths there.
On on hand, it goes through the right hand switch and out through wire (1). That wire then connects to the lamp. The lamp also has a separate neutral wire going to it, but that's not visible here. Or perhaps it's one of the white wires in the background - we can't tell.
On the other hand, power also goes through the (2-4) wire and into the left switch, then through it, and out again through wire (5). This wire is connected to the fan, which, like the lamp, also has a neutral cable going to it.
So, to replace the right switch, but not affect the left switch, you need to keep (2) and (3) together, and connect both to the input side of the new dimmer switch. Then connect (1) to the output side of the dimmer switch.
However... your dimmer switch has 4 wires coming out of it. I've no idea which  one is which and what the other 2 wires are for. I also don't have any experience with dimmer switches, but if you could send some link to a webpage describing this particular switch, I could probably figure that out.

It looks like a typical North American 3-way dimmer -- the black lead is equivalent to the differently colored screw, and the two red leads are interchangeable with each other

This looks like they are using the backstab on the switch to pass power through. So power comes in to the right switch via the screw terminal, then heads out from there to the left switch. If you want to replace the switch, you should add a wire connector between the two wires. Since your dimmer switch has wire leads, you can add the power lead from the dimmer switch into that wire connector. Terminal 1 should be the output wire that goes from the dimmer switch to the light.

That backstabs don't make any sense, particularly the #3 wire—why not just use the terminal clamp like you did for wire #2?  Just laziness on the part of the installer, I guess.

@Huesmann Inconsistent laziness, too. On the other switch, the red wire is backstabbed at #5, but not the black wire at #4. Quite odd. Seeing this, I would take apart, inspect and redo it all.

@Alexander: Whether it's inconsistent depends on how you look at it. All the connections to other locations (panel, lights etc) are backstabbed; all the connections between the switches use the screws. That's a sort of consistency - of course, whether it's in any way a good idea is a different question!

Backstabs where it's easy and screws when you have to is something I've run into plenty of times before in residential construction.

@Alexander yeah, I noticed that too.
